# How to make regular lines jump like connectors

Tags: visio, shapesheet

Exactly like the title says, how can I make a regular line behave like a connector and jump over other connectors?

Answer (score 1):

The question is old, but I just had the same problem with Visio (App on Windows 10). In my case, y4cine's answer did not work because I was missing an option in the page setup. So you need to:

- Use the connectors.
- Set the line jump style.

To set the line jump, simply:

- Access the page setup by right-clicking your page tab.
- Go to Layout and Routing.
- Line jumps.
- Line jump style: Arc

This is the option that I was missing.
See also: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-or-remove-connector-line-jumps-1a5516db-0212-4352-90dd-fc9cfd4018ed

Answer (score 0):

Use a connector and set its appearance to straight. (right mouse click)